# World Position in glsl for three.js instanced mesh

Tags: three.js, glsl

I’m trying to get world space texture coordinate for instanced meshes in three.js using glsl, it works for individual objects but not for instanced meshes.

```
W_Pos = (modelMatrix * vec4(position,1.0)).xyz;
```

individual objects
[image]

instances
[image: instances]

any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm so dumb, the answer was in the docs, i had read that before but it completely slipped my mind lel.

```
W_Pos = instanceMatrix * vec3(position,1.0).xyz;
```

https://threejs.org/docs/?q=web#api/en/renderers/webgl/WebGLProgram